# Freestyle SVG Export decimated landscape

Tags: modifiers, wireframe, svg

Hello blender community,

I'm trying to export a decimated "wireframe" of a landscape. Import is, that the single elements of the wireframe are rectangles, like you can see on this image:

[image: example]

I'm on a good way and my current solution follows these steps:

- add landscape (with A.N.T. landscape add-on)
- use decimate modifier to reduce the segments on the landscape
- select landscape
- Edge -> Mark freestyle Edge
- Check "Edge Mark" on Freestyle Line Set layer property

With this process I'm getting close to the example I wanna reach but the biggest difference is, that my segments are triangles and not rectangles:

[image: my solution]

Do you have any tips how to get closer to the original?
Thanks for your help! Please keep in mind that I'm a total beginner in the 3d world and in blender.

Comment: Try using a displacement map on a quad plane. That way, you will always have a perfect quad grid

Comment: Does setting the decimate modifier to "unsubdivide" do what you want?